# Sprite.curveTo with Imagick in PHP

Tags: php, actionscript, imagemagick

I'm looking for the equivalent function of `sprite.graphics.curveTo()` in ActionScript for PHP with Imagick.
[List of function which may do the trick :](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.imagickdraw.php)

```
bool pathCurveToAbsolute ( float $x1 , float $y1 , float $x2 , float $y2 , float $x , float $y )
bool pathCurveToQuadraticBezierAbsolute ( float $x1 , float $y1 , float $x , float $y )
bool pathCurveToQuadraticBezierRelative ( float $x1 , float $y1 , float $x , float $y )
bool pathCurveToQuadraticBezierSmoothAbsolute ( float $x , float $y )
bool pathCurveToQuadraticBezierSmoothRelative ( float $x , float $y )
bool pathCurveToRelative ( float $x1 , float $y1 , float $x2 , float $y2 , float $x , float $y )
bool pathCurveToSmoothAbsolute ( float $x2 , float $y2 , float $x , float $y )
bool pathCurveToSmoothRelative ( float $x2 , float $y2 , float $x , float $y )
```

Which one is it ? Any ideas ?? Because I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash curveTo is a quadratic Bézier curve, equivalent to php ImagickDraw::pathCurveToQuadraticBezierAbsolute

[Abode: Drawing lines and curves](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd9.html)

> The curveTo() method draws a quadratic Bézier curve. This draws an arc
>   that connects two points (called anchor points) while bending toward a
>   third point (called the control point). The Graphics object uses the
>   current drawing position as the first anchor point. When you call the
>   curveTo() method, you pass four parameters: the x and y coordinates of
>   the control point, followed by the x and y coordinates of the second
>   anchor point. For example, the following code draws a curve starting
>   at point 100, 100 and ending at point 200, 200. Because the control
>   point is at point 175, 125, this creates a curve that moves to the
>   right and then downward:

[AS3 implementation (flash.display.Graphics)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html):

```
curveTo(controlX:Number, controlY:Number, anchorX:Number, anchorY:Number):void
```

[PHP implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.pathcurvetoquadraticbezierabsolute.php):

```
bool ImagickDraw::pathCurveToQuadraticBezierAbsolute ( float $x1 , float $y1 , float $x , float $y )
```